# pyodbc console error message

Tags: python, pyodbc

How can I display the console output of a non-table returning query?

e.g.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 12.0};Server=...')
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = """
    ALTER DATABASE XXXX
    SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

    RESTORE DATABASE XXXX
    FROM DISK = '\\path\to\file\XXXX.bak'
"""
cursor.execute(sql)
```

I get the following error message on MS SQL Server Management Studio, but not sure how to see it in python w/pyodbc.

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot open backup device '\\path\to\file\XXXX.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

But Pyodbc runs without throwing any exceptions, and is as normal.
Printing the cursor object just returns the cursor object, and `.fetchall()` only works on result queries.

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` immediately before your ALTER DATABASE statement.

Comment: @GordThompson , I get `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.`

Comment: Your code block does not return a result set, so calling `fetchone`, `fetchall`, etc. is not necessary. Does the updated code block not throw an exception in Python if it fails?